# Display array of values in field Kendo Grid

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to display array of values inside a single field in kendo grid. Is it possible to do this

**Scenario** : For some columns in each row of the grid I'm getting a list of values per row and need to display them comma separated. So given values `['a','b']` I need to display in the column as `a,b`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

In the column definition, define a template that users `jQuery.join` method.

Example: If the field is `Cities` (the array), it would be something like:

```
{ field: "Cities", width: 300, template: "#= Cities.join(', ') #" }
```